# Webpack analysis fix "Multiple references to the same module"

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I have a simple script e.g.

```
import AppEnum from 'Libs/app.enum';

export default class MyObject {
    func1() {
        ....
        if (AppEnum.val === 'x'){
        ....
        }
        if (AppEnum.val2 === 'y'){
        ....
        }
        if (AppEnum.val2 === 'z'){
        ....
        }
    }
    func2() {
        ....
        if (AppEnum.val === 'x'){
        ....
        }
        if (AppEnum.val2 === 'y'){
        ....
        }
        if (AppEnum.val2 === 'z'){
        ....
        }
    }
}
```

When i run `webpack --profile --json > analysis.json`
and load the file on http://webpack.github.io/analyse
I receive the hint "Multiple references to the same module" (used 6 times)
if i change the above code to

```
import AppEnum from 'Libs/app.enum';
const myAppEnum = AppEnum;
```

and rename the references to myAppEnum i still receive the same error but with less number of views (2 to be exact)

What i am doing wrong ? What is the proper way to refer to my AppEnum?